Flat List not rendering
My FlatList is not rendering even after I have logged the data coming from the API on the console. Here is my code:
import { FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import GlobalApi from '../Utils/GlobalApi';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const CategoryList = () => {
  const getCategory =()=>{
    GlobalApi.getCategory().then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.categories);
      setCategories(resp.categories)
    })
  }
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState();
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={categories}
        horizontal={true}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({item,index}) => (
          <View>
            <Image source={{uri:item?.icon?.url}} 
              style={{width:40, height: 40}}
            />
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
          </View>
  )}      
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default CategoryList

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})


You defined a getCategory function to fetch the data, but are not calling it anywhere in your code.

Thank You. It just rendered now after I called getCategory with useEffect. But the images aren't rendering in the flatlist, just item.name

I've always had to use require with a relative path for images as they do in the example docs:  source={require('./path/to/image.png')}, note if the image is not part of the bundle use the src property


You should initialize categories to an empty array to avoid any
potential issues when FlatList tries to render. Additionally, make
sure your FlatList is given a valid style or View
below is the code also i have added the dummy data for icons also
icons are working in the flatlist

const CategoryList = () => {   const [categories, setCategories] =
 useState([]);
 
  const getCategory = () => {
     GlobalApi.getCategory().then(resp => {
       console.log(resp.categories);
      setCategories(resp.categories);
     }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });   }; 
   useEffect(() => {
     const dummyData = [
      { id: '1', icon: { url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/40' } },
      { id: '2', icon: { url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/40' } },
      { id: '3', icon: { url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/40' } },
    ];
   setCategories(dummyData);   }, []);


below is the ui code  also i have share the expo snack link and you
can modify the code there

 <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={categories}
        horizontal={true}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            <Image 
              source={{ uri: item?.icon?.url }} 
              style={styles.image} 
            />
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>

Expo Link
